# OpenLDAP 2.4.23 - Debian 6.0 - Import schema - Insufficient access (50)

Tags: openldap

Good day to everybody.

I'm trying to add a new schema inside OpenLDAP. But getting an error:

```
ldap_add: Insufficient access (50)
```

`root@ldap:/# ldapadd -c -x -D cn=admin,dc=domain,dc=com -W -f  /tmp/test.d/cn\=config/cn\=schema/cn\=\{5\}microsoft.ldif`

```
root@ldap:/# cat /tmp/test.d/cn\=config/cn\=schema/cn\=\{5\}microsoft.ldif
dn: cn=microsoft,cn=schema,cn=config
objectClass: olcSchemaConfig
cn: microsoft
olcAttributeTypes: {0}( 1.2.840.113556.1.4.302 NAME 'sAMAccountType' DESC 'Fss
 ssully qualified name of distinguished Java class or interface' SYNTAX 1.3.6.
 1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.27 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: {1}( 1.2.840.113556.1.4.146 NAME 'objectSid' DESC 'Fssssull
 y qualified name of distinguished Java class or interfaced' SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.
 1.1466.115.121.1.40 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: {2}( 1.2.840.113556.1.4.221 NAME 'sAMAccountName' DESC 'Fds
 sssully qualified name of distinguished Java class or interfaced' SYNTAX 1.3.
 6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: {3}( 1.2.840.113556.1.4.1412 NAME 'primaryGroupToken' SYNTA
 X 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.27 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: {4}( 1.2.840.113556.1.2.102 NAME 'memberOf' SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.
 4.1.1466.115.121.1.12 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: {5}( 1.2.840.113556.1.4.98 NAME 'primaryGroupID' SYNTAX 1.3
 .6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.27 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcObjectClasses: {0}( 1.2.840.113556.1.5.6 NAME 'securityPrincipal' DESC 'Cso
 ntainer for a Java object' SUP top AUXILIARY MUST ( objectSid $ sAMAccountNam
 e ) MAY ( primaryGroupToken $ memberOf $ primaryGroupID ) )
```

I also tried to add the schema by phpldapadmin, but gain the same error.

I'm using the admin user which is specified by default from the begging of the slpad installation. How may I add permissions to this user ?

Best wishes

Comment: I'm not using slapd.conf file. Using CN=CONFIG

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default access config for cn=config is to only allow via external auth. Try:

`ldapadd -c -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f '/tmp/test.d/cn=config/cn=schema/cn={5}microsoft.ldif'`

Comment: root@ldap:/# ldapadd -c -Y EXTERNAL -H ldap://90.0.0.97/ -f '/tmp/test.d/cn=config/cn=schema/cn={5}microsoft.ldif'
SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
ldap_sasl_interactive_bind_s: Unknown authentication method (-6)
        additional info: SASL(-4): no mechanism available:

90.0.0.97 is a private IP placed in private network. I guess the problem may come because the local DNS is not resolving this address correctly ?

Comment: Stupidity is something dangerous nowadays ...

ldapadd -c -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f 
'/tmp/test.d/cn=config/cn=schema/cn={5}microsoft.ldif'
SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
SASL username: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
SASL SSF: 0
adding new entry "cn=microsoft,cn=schema,cn=config"